# "Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points..." - each VC has a Storyboard ID - Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am getting two instances of the following issue:

```
Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.
```

I have already done the following:

1. Made sure each view controller has a storyboard ID
2. Made sure that no view controller has a hidden duplicate
3. Cleaned the project

'Initial view controller' is checked on the relevant view controller of course. When I click the issue it doesn't show me where in the storyboard I can find the culprit.

Comment: ohh..just add identifier for your view controller in Storyborad and use the same identifier when you are loading the screen.

Comment: I have an identifier for all view controllers. What do you mean 'use the same identifier when you are loading the screen'? In what way am I supposed to 'use' the identifier other than referencing it in code?

Comment: let me explain..suppose your viewcontroller identifier is "ViewIdentifier", then in coding you have to write as  below

instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:"ViewIdentifier"

Comment: He already said that all his view controllers have a storyboard ID (which I assume is the identifier you're talking about).

Comment: @Gagan_iOS That's what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seem like you've tried all the obvious things, so here are a few suggestions:

- Check that none of your storyboard id's are duplicates.
- Double check that all your navigation controllers have storyboard ID's too.
- Check that you've assigned the correct class to each VC in the right panel.
- Remove all storyboard ID's, build, then try to set them all again.